# Gradle: Exclude files from PlayBinary distribution

Tags: gradle, playframework, build.gradle

I have the following configuration in my build.gradle file: how can I exclude certain `**/*.conf` files from getting into the target binary ?

```
   distributions {
            playBinary {
                baseName = 'my-service'
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the content of the distribution using `contents` as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html#sec:distribution_contents) . Then you can apply any filtering using `CopySpec` (see [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) API ).

Example, if your distribution root directory is `src/playBinary`

```
distributions {
    playBinary {
        baseName = 'my-service'
        contents {
            from ('src/playBinary' ){
                exclude '**/*.conf'
            }
        }
    }
}
```